# Drawing bar charts vertically after each other d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

so what I'm trying to do is draw a bar chart below a bar chart i already have created.

so this is the scale i have initially used

```
  this.visScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'OT'])
      .range([this.dims.margins.left, this.dims.width - this.dims.margins.right])
      .paddingInner(0.1);
```

This splits the SVG into 5 pieces theoretically, but the problem is it doesn't expand vertically just horizontally.

I've tried to change the range multiple time, but to no avail.

this is a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Any more info required, just ask.

Comment: You will need a total of 3 or 4 scales depending upon if your home and away points are segregated. Two questions: 1. What is on the x-axis? Is it date-time? 2. Is it possible to provide some sample data?

Comment: The x axis is just a linear scale of 12 minutes down to 0, I'll provide you with some sample data, https://gist.github.com/Ox29A/32c0f16c481e152e3048c7182050dd54,To give you a bit more context I'm mapping all the goals from a basketball game into segregated quarters, any more questions just ask.

Comment: Your range would need to be with respect to the height and not the width. Therefore `.range([this.dims.margins.top, this.dims.height - this.dims.margins.bottom])`. Could you post more of the code you have tried?

Comment: these are the scales i attempted to create initially. https://gist.github.com/Ox29A/160386e2393242e7e3e5ccefabf49544

Comment: Here is the full source to spread some light: https://gist.github.com/Ox29A/8997ab4694117543fa3df2ad62e1598e

Comment: "but the problem is it doesn't expand vertically just horizontally" - can you elaborate this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i managed to solve it myself.

```
 this.visScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain([1, 2, 3, 4]) // q1, q2, q3, q4
  .range([this.dims.margins.top, this.dims.height - this.dims.margins.bottom])
  .paddingInner(0.05)
  .paddingOuter(0);

this.xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .paddingInner(0.05)
  .paddingOuter(0)
  .range([this.dims.margins.left, this.dims.width - this.dims.margins.right]);

this.scoreScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-5, 10])
  .range([0, this.visScale.bandwidth()]);
```

this gives this includes vertical axis's such as score scale, but we can specify by numbers, 1 - 4 which will change the y position.